# Wildfly 11 - infinispan local Cache is not registering

Tags: infinispan, wildfly-11

I am using local cache in wildfly 11. While accessing cache i am getting below error
>

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: infinispan/container/SearchContainer [Root exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException]
>       at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:153)
>       at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:83)
>       at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
>       at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:184)
>       at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:239)
>       at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:193)
>       at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:189)
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
>       at org.jboss.msc.value.InjectedValue.getValue(InjectedValue.java:47)
>       at org.jboss.as.naming.service.BinderService.getValue(BinderService.java:142)
>       at org.jboss.as.naming.service.BinderService.getValue(BinderService.java:46)
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.getValue(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1158)
>       at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:131)
>       ... 174 more

standalone configuration as follows,

```
<cache-container name="SearchContainer" default-cache="TwoColumnSearchCache" jndi-name="java:jboss/infinispan/container/SearchContainer">
            <local-cache name="TwoColumnSearchCache">
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="-1"/>
                <expiration lifespan="60000" max-idle="60000"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
```

In managed bean, i have tried two ways, both are not working in wildfly 11. But in Wildfly 10, it was working fine with same code.

Way 1 :

```
CacheContainer searchContainer = (CacheContainer) new InitialContext().lookup("java:jboss/infinispan/container/SearchContainer");
Cache<String, List<Map<String, String>>> twoColumnSearchCache = searchContainer.getCache("TwoColumnSearchCache");
```

Way 2:

```
@Resource(lookup="java:jboss/infinispan/container/SearchContainer/TwoColumnSearchCache")
Cache<String, List<Map<String, String>>> twoColumnSearchCache ;
```

How should I use the cache in wildfly 11?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In WF11, cache configuration services are installed on demand, thus using a resource reference (e.g. @Resource, resource-ref, resource-env-ref) for a cache manager is not sufficient to ensure that its cache configurations are installed. You need to either, add an additional @Resource/resource-ref/resource-env-ref for the cache configuration, or (even better) just lookup the cache directly by using a resource-env-ref for the cache itself.
e.g.

Deployment descriptor:

```
<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>TwoColumnSearchCache</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>org.infinispan.Cache</resource-env-ref-type>
    <lookup-name>java:jboss/infinispan/cache/SearchContainer/TwoColumnSearchCache</lookup-name>
</resource-env-ref>
```

Then reference your cache via:

```
@Resource(name="TwoColumnSearchCache")
Cache<String, List<Map<String, String>>> cache;
```